# Seebeck Coefficient. Microscopic understanding of seebeck effect

Tags: thermoelectricity

> For the thermoelectric effect, now, consider the case of uniform
>   voltage (uniform chemical potential) with a temperature gradient. In
>   this case, at the hotter side of the material there is more variation
>   in the energies of the charge carriers, compared to the colder side.
>   This means that high energy levels have a higher carrier occupation
>   per state on the hotter side, but also the hotter side has a lower
>   occupation per state at lower energy levels.

Can somebody explain this statement to me. What's the meaning of "higher carrier occupation per state" and "lower occupation per state" . And why does hot side has both of them?

Edit: Source of the quoted material-

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seebeck_coefficient

Comment: Welcome to the site! We normally expect textual quotes to be accompanied to a reference to the original source.

Answer (score 1):

The quote says how the Fermi-Dirac distribution behaves as a function of temperature.

Here is an image [from Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Fermi-Verteilung_(Temperatur).svg):

[image: Fermi-Dirac distrubutions]